# Double loop in R with a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I know the error that I commit, but I cannot find any solution. I'm programming a double loop for simulating with the Monte Carlo method.

```
set.seed(-1256,normal.kind="Box-Muller")
A <- matrix(Nsimul,85)
for (k in 1:Nsimul) {
    r=c()
    r[1]=r0_CIR
    S=c()
    S[1]=I0
    A[,1]=r0_CIR
    for(j in 1:NumPassi){
        epsilon=rnorm(2,0,1)
        r[j+1]= r[j]+alphaStar*(gammaStar-r[j])*Deltat + rho*sqrt(r[j])*epsilon[1]*sqrt(Deltat)
        if (r[j+1]<0) r[j+1]=abs(r[j+1])
        epsilon_S=epsilon[1]+sqrt(1-corr^2)*epsilon[2]
        S[j+1]=S[j]*exp((r[j]-sigma^2/2-div)*Deltat+sigma*epsilon_S*sqrt(Deltat))
        A[k,j+1]=r[j+1]
    }
}
```

when I try to run the code I have this error

```
 Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , j + 1, value = 0.0102279735166489) : subscript out of bounds
```

I don't understand which value is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may incrementally grow vectors by calling indeces that don't exist (not a great practice but I digress), for example

```
S<-c()
S[1]<-1
S
#[1] 1
```

You may not do so in the method you are trying to with the matrix A in your example.

Here is an example matrix I made

```
A<-matrix(1:10, nrow=5)
#         [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]    2    7
#[3,]    3    8
#[4,]    4    9
#[5,]    5   10
```

and if I try

```
A[1,3]<-1
```

I get

```
#Error in A[1, 3] <- 2 : subscript out of bounds
```

While you have many things undefined in your question, such as A, Numsimul, Numpassi, so I can't know for sure what's going on, but the final line of the second for loop is most likely the issue.  If the value for j becomes larger than the number of columns in your matrix A, then you will have an error thrown on you.

You must ensure that the column exists first before you begin setting it in the second for loop